# how to get playback song in asterisk dialplan

Tags: shell, asterisk

I want to get the playback song while listening using asterisk dial plan

exten => s,n,Playback(facebook/english/song1)
he will listen song song1.mp3 i need to get this song name using dial plan

Comment: Explain better what you want.
Playback is "blocking" application, so it will not return control until file is completely played.
So, either you want to know which file has been already played, or you want to use Background application and in some next steps after call of Background you want to know which file is currenty playing.
In case of Background I have few thoughts, but you should explain yourself first.

Comment: i want to capture the name of the song played via playback function so that i can share the song name on fb wall.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
exten => s,n,Set(SONG_TO_PLAY=${SHELL(/usr/local/asterisk/very_complicated_script_to_get_next_song_to_play.sh arg1 arg2 arg3):0:-1})
exten => s,n,Playback(${SONG_TO_PLAY})
exten => s,n,System(/usr/local/asterisk/notify_fb.sh ${SONG_TO_PLAY})
```

I know nothing about your Asterisk installation, so I suggest you are using some linux and can easily execute shell-commands. That is why in that example I use System application and SHELL function. Btw, SHELL functions works on asterisk version >= 1.6.

In your environment you can use AGI, CURL, ODBC or anything you like to accomplish outbound operations instead of using System and SHELL.